# How can i call variable into another function in django?

Tags: django, pandas

```
def upload(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        file_p = form.save().document
        df = pd.read_csv(file_p, header=None) #parsing CSV file
        df.drop([0], axis=1, inplace=True)


        return render(request, 'Data/csv.html', {'df': df})


else:
    form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'Data/upload.html', {'form': form})
```

This is a function. I need to call **df** in another function:

```
def mean(request):
    df['Average_Income'] = df.mean(axis=1).astype(int)
    return render(request, 'Data/mean.html', {'df': df})
```

Comment: can anyone please answer this? I have a deadline tomorrow.

Comment: We don't care about your deadlines - SO is not a "do my homework for free" service.

Comment: @Wariored oh yeah globals in a wsgi app, great suggestion. Have fun debugging this once it's in production.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use session variables but seems your `df` variable read a csv file by pandas libraby. So I would do the same thing as in your first function in every view I need `df`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_p, header=None) #parsing CSV file
df.drop([0], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Or declare `df` at the top of your file as global variable

Comment: You can use globals in a wsgi app too

Answer (score -1):

You can store that data in request session value, and you can get that value in other function.

```
request.session['key'] = value # to set the value

value = request.session['key']  # get value in another function
```

Comment: Why use a session when there's obviously a way to identify the document ?